# Making an "NSManaged public var" an Optional Boolean

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

How can I make an `NSManaged public var` an optional boolean? When I type the following:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit

extension SomeClass {

    @NSManaged public var isLiked: Bool?
    @NSManaged public var isDisliked: Bool?

}
```

I get the error:

**Property cannot be marked @NSManaged because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C**

What I want is a property that can be neither `liked` or `disliked`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `@NSManaged`, you have to follow its rules. Those rules include working with ObjC, which doesn't have optionals. But you don't have to use `@NSManaged`, even when using Core Data. You can drop it as long as you implement your own accessors. Something like:

```
public var isLiked : Bool? {
    get {
        willAccessValue(forKey: "isLiked")
        let isLiked = primitiveValue(forKey: "isLiked") as! Int64
        didAccessValue(forKey: "isLiked")
        return isLiked
    }
    set {
        willChangeValue(forKey: "isLiked")
        setPrimitiveValue(newValue, forKey: "isLiked")
        didChangeValue(forKey: "isLiked")
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct that @NSManaged types must be compatible with ObjC.  However, the issue here is not with the optional, but with the Swift Bool type.  Swift's Bool type is an object and is not compatible with/equivalent to ObjC's BOOL primitive type.

Answer (score 4):

Tom Harrington's answer is correct that the @NSManaged types must work with ObjC.  However, the issue is not with the optional type.  @NSManaged types may be optional, e.g.:

```
@NSManaged var someProperty: String?
```

The issue here is with the Swift Bool type.  Swift's Bool is an object and is not the same as ObjC primitive type BOOL.  For a CoreData entity with a Boolean property, you should use the NSNumber? type as the @NSManaged property in your code.  Then, similar to Tom's answer you could setup a separate Bool accessor property to get/set the @NSManaged NSNumber property, for example:

```
// the "liked" property is a Boolean attribute in your CoreData entity
@NSManaged var liked: NSNumber?

var isLiked: Bool? {
    get { return Bool(exactly: liked) }
    set { liked = NSNumber(booleanLiteral: newValue) }
}
```

The `isLiked` property will allow you to use it in your code like a Bool, but under the hood CoreData stores the value as an NSNumber for the Boolean attribute in your CoreData entity.

Answer (score 0):

This can possibly be a reason you get that issue, if you have your Codegen set to manual. You have to make sure when you create an `NSObject` Subclass that all attributes are preset and no other attributes need to be added afterwards.

If you try adding a new attribute after already creating the `NSObject` Subclass then you will get this error.

Solution for me: Delete you subclass and properties file and go back to your `.xcdatamodeld` file and regenerate them with all the attributes that you want.